# Django не может сделать коннект к бд postgres

Tags: база-данных, django, postgresql, centos7, psycopg2

ОС - Centos7

```
sudo -u postgres -i
psql 
CREATE DATABASE test1;
CREATE USER test1 WITH PASSWORD 'test111';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE test1 TO test1;
```

мой pg_hba.conf

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            ident
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 ident
```

В settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'test1',
        'USER': 'test1',
        'PASSWORD': 'test111',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

При запуске `python manage.py makemigrations` получаю:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/karavan/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/karavan/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/karavan/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 168, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/karavan/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "test1"


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/karavan/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/karavan/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/karavan/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/karavan/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/karavan/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 92, in handle
    loader.check_consistent_history(connection)
  File "/home/karavan/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 275, in check_consistent_history
    applied = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/karavan/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 61, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/home/karavan/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 44, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "/home/karavan/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 255, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/home/karavan/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 232, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home/karavan/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/karavan/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/karavan/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/karavan/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/karavan/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 168, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/karavan/env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "test1"
```

На Ubuntu с этим все было ок, а Centos не хочет)

**UPD** 
Сделал юзера без пароля и такую же ошибку выбивает, поэтому нет, ошибка не в неверном пароле

Comment: Ругается на креды: `django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "test1"` Возможно, неправильный пароль

Comment: @Klimenkomud 2 раза создавал разных юзеров и перепроверял/копировал пароль, думаю это исключено :с

Comment: измените в pg_hba метод ident на md5

Comment: @godva спасибо огромное! Помогло!)